# LDAP plugin: user authentication fails after upgrade

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

After having migrated to SonarQube 5.6, LDAP 2.1 (from SonarQube 5.3, LDAP 1.5)

When authenticating against an Active Directory domain I get the following error

```
2016.12.16 15:56:31 ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:
```

*Please notice that*

During the migration I have had to add the following parameters in order to get the LDAP plugin to recognize the working domain

```
ldap.realm=company.domain
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
```

In the logs I find

```
Test LDAP connection on ldap://servername.company.domain: OK
```

Comment: Well, looks like SonarSource has splitted the LDAP plugin:
the Active Directory related code has been dropped (moved to the Active Directory plugin, a community supported plugin), probably to retain only the LDAP related functions in their enterprise supported plugin.
Releases for the Active Directory plugin: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDAP plugin (supported by SonarSource) doesn't include anymore the [active-directory related code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-ldap/pull/19).

This code is now contained in the community supported plugin [Active Directory plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory/blob/master/README.md)

Honestly, I haven't found any trace of this change in their official documentation. I have found it while browsing the code of the LDAP plugin (because when I finally completed its configuration to match my domain, I noticed that the users created by the LDAP plugin were not matching the existing users => loss of privileges)

Enabling the Active Directory plugin (and disabling the LDAP one) allowed me to get the same feature level as in SonarQube 5.3, LDAP 1.5

Comment: I was having the exact same issue (i.e. login fails after upgrade to 5.6 LTS with LDAP 2.1 plugin in use) and was able to make login to the SonarQube server work again by using the Active Directory plugin as you suggested.